# Как привести переданный объект типа object к его истинному типу?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-commands

Есть `RootVM` и, как многие знают, в нём реализована команда для смены `CurrentContentVM`-свойства.

```
public Command ChangeRootContentCommand
{ 
    get
    {
        return new Command(
            content =>
            {
                RootContentData pars = (RootContentData)content;

                switch (pars.ContentVMType)
                {
                    case ContentVMs.TestingStartSection:
                        CurrentContentVM = (TestingStartSection)pars.ContentVM;
                        break;
                    case ContentVMs.TestingTicketsSection:
                        CurrentContentVM = (TestingTicketsSection)pars.ContentVM;
                        break;
                    case ContentVMs.TestingResultsSection:
                        CurrentContentVM = (TestingResultsSection)pars.ContentVM;
                        break;
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

### Как я привожу к нудному типу

В метод `Command.Execute` должен передаваться объект специального класса `RootContentData`. Он выглядит так:

```
enum ContentVMs
{
    DataBaseControlVM,
    TestingStartSection,
    TestingTicketsSection,
    TestingResultsSection
}
class RootContentData
{
    public RootContentData(object contentVM, ContentVMs contentVMType)
    {
        ContentVM      = contentVM;
        ContentVMType  = contentVMType;
    }
    public object ContentVM { get; set; }
    public ContentVMs ContentVMType { get; set; }
}
```

Конструктор этого класса принимает 2 аргумента: экземпляр другой `VM` и её тип, к которому нужно эту `VM` привести в команде `ChangeRootContentCommand`.

И, как видно из кода команды, чтобы привести переданный экземпляр `VM` к её типу:

1. Я привожу переданный объект к типу `RootContentData`;
2. Затем в блоке `switch` я сравниваю его свойство `ContentVMType` с перечислением, хранящим все "виды" `VM`.
3. Если совпадение находится, привожу экземпляр, переданной в качестве свойства `RootContentData.ContentVM`, `VM`ки к её типу.

### Можно ли проще?

Мне кажется, что я таким образом создал "замудрённый" велосипед. Как **упростить** процесс приведения экземпляра `VM` к её типу?

Comment: А зачем вам тут вообще каст, если вы скармливаете это все в `CurrentContentVM`, который имеет один тип? Да и вообще вам не должно хотеться получить тип, ибо это по сути DataContext, к которому лишь идет привязка и какого он типа тут без разницы, главное чтоб было публичное свойство для привязки, все.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо! Уже и не помню с чего это я это придумал) Учиться, учиться и ещё раз учиться! P.S. А всё таки вы можете подсказать лучший способ привести объект к его типу? Вне контекста wpf.

Comment: А почему бы не сделать дженериком? RootContentData<T> ? и свойство сделать типом T а не object

Comment: Ну тут вариантов много по сути. Обычно подобное обобщают, создавая некий интерфейс, который имеет общие методы и тогда просто используется этот интерфейс. Вообще, ваш класс можно вовсе убрать, а switch заменить на `if (obj is TestingStartSection startSection) { /*..*/ } else if (obj is TestingTicketsSection ticketsSection) { /*..*/ }...` и уже с этим дальше играться как надо.